# keep activity alive after testcase using robotium

Tags: android, junit, robotium

Hiii i am testing a test method in which i want after a pressing a button my activity should alive so that i can see next test cases in that activity,but unfortunately my activity get killed after running the test case .is there any way to keep the activity  alive.if there code line please let me inform.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure without seeing your code, but i am guessing either in the testcase, or the setup() and tearDown() methods you are going to have to been calling a method such as finishOpenedActivities() which closes all the activities you have open. removing this line will keep the activity open.

Having said that it is typically best practice to have your test cases start from a clean state because having test cases that rely on ordering means that if one fails all the others fail even if that functionality does work plus you have to do slightly hacky things in order to get them to all run in the order you want.

Comment: yes but i have tried to remove finishOpenedActivities() from my tearDown() method still its not working and i want my activity run for some specified time becoz i want to see what is happening after pressing a a button.is there any other suggestion from you thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the source code a bit and found that the `tearDown()` method, as implemented in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, will make a call to `finish()` on your current activity. So even if you don't explicitly finish() you Activity in your implementation of this method, it will be done when calling `super`.  However, per the source code documentation: removing the call to super in tearDown() can cause a memory leak if you have a non-static inner class, and, perhaps more importantly for your case, the running Activity seems to still be killed once the test is completed.  Even if you have an empty implementation of tearDown(), it seems as though the Activity Under Test gets finished at the end of the run. As of right now, I don't know of a way to avoid this.

As an alternative based on your comment for @Paul Harris's answer, Robotium has many methods that allow you to wait for something to happen.  You may want to look into `waitForText()` or `waitForView()`, which can take a timeout as a argument, to have Robotium pause while your button click is performing some action. Hope this helps!

Comment: Here i removed super() and solo.finishOpenedActivities(); from my tearDown() method the actving is alive after testcase pass but i want the activity should alive for some specified time .how to achive this

Comment: You can use `solo.sleep(milliseconds)` to have Robotium wait.  Robotium runs on its own thread, so putting it to sleep will allow your UI to continue to execute as normal.  I still think that using a waitFor method is preferable if what you're staying alive for will update the UI, that way you can assert that whatever it is actually happens.

Comment: Can we Test GPS Using robotium if it is not possible in robotium is  it achivable by using any other test framework.

Comment: That's a very broad question, but yes, there are ways to use Robotium to ensure that your GPS code is working properly.  If you're having a specific issue with this, feel free to post another question!